# How do I find which articles are missing a featured image in The WordPress database?

Tags: posts, database, post-thumbnails, mysql, sql

How do I search the database to find out which articles are missing a featured image on them? I looked around in the `wp_posts` table and searched `post_type` is equal to article. It gives me a list of all articles but the guid filed has images and no way to see which ones are empty. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want it to know in which article you need to edit and add featured image.

You can create some file in the worpdress root folder and just use `WP_Query` to get all the posts and to check if there is no feature image you can use the `has_post_thumbnail()`.

Change the `post_type` if needed.

Example

```
<?php
require_once('./wp-load.php');
$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post'));
if ( $query->have_posts() ) while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    if(has_post_thumbnail() === false) {
    ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br>
    <?php
    }
endwhile;
```

If you still want to use the SQL you can create `WP_Query` and take the generated SQL. You can also use this `WP_Query` like the first method and you don't need to check if `has_post_thumbnail()` is false.

```
$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type'=>'post',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            )
        )
    )
);
echo ($query->request); // Print the SQL
```

So the SQL for this example after I modify it is a little.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON
(wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' )
WHERE 1=1  AND (wp_postmeta.post_id IS NULL) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to do it in the database though?

Comment: @MikeL5799 see the answer now

Comment: Thanks so I just ran the query in sql and nothing comes up. my post type is called expert advice. Where would I change that? where `wp_posts.post_type = 'post'` correct?

Comment: Yes. You also need to change the table prefix if it's other than `wp_` better use the second wp_quey first and get the correct SQL for you

Comment: I have been looking to find posts with missing featured images, but didn't want to create any files or query the database. This [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-image-admin-thumb-fiat/) shows featured image column in WP - All Posts. It's easy to scroll down or Ctrl+F and look for "Set featured image".

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT guid 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_type = "post" 
AND ID NOT IN (
   SELECT post_id as `ID` 
   FROM wp_postmeta 
   WHERE meta_key = "_thumbnail_id"
) 
ORDER BY `wp_posts`.`guid` ASC;
```

What's happeninng here?

1. Find all the entries in the wp_posts table that are for the post type "Post"
2. Look for all existing post meta entries for the Featured Image, grab me all of those IDs
3. Now filter out the IDs from step 2

The results left over are for posts that don't have a featured image